# Merge map of arrays with duplicate keys

Tags: java, java-8, hashmap

I have two maps of arrays.

```
Map<String, List<String>> map1 = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, List<String>> map2 = new HashMap<>();
```

I want to merge them in one new map.
If a key exists in both maps, in that case, I should merge arrays.

For example:

```
map1.put("k1", Arrays.asList("a0", "a1"));
map1.put("k2", Arrays.asList("b0", "b1"));

map2.put("k2", Arrays.asList("z1", "z2"));

// Expected output is 
Map 3: {k1=[a0, a1], k2=[b0, b1, z1, z2]}
```

I tried to do that with streams

```
Map<String, List<String>> map3 = Stream.of(map1, map2)
    .flatMap(map -> map.entrySet().stream())
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        Map.Entry::getKey,
        e -> e.getValue().stream().collect(Collectors.toList())
    ));
```

This work if there are no the same keys in maps. Otherwise, I get the exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Duplicate key k2 (attempted merging values [b0, b1] and [z1, z2])
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Collectors.duplicateKeyException(Collectors.java:133)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Collectors.lambda$uniqKeysMapAccumulator$1(Collectors.java:180)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$3ReducingSink.accept(ReduceOps.java:169)
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap$EntrySpliterator.forEachRemaining(HashMap.java:1751)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:658)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:274)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578)
    at im.djm.Test.main(Test.java:25)
```

Is there a way to accomplish this task with streams?
Or I have to iterate throug maps?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with *not* using streams. On the contrary. It's more readable and faster without.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use a merge function in the case of duplicate keys:

```
Map<String, List<String>> map3 = Stream.of(map1, map2)
                .flatMap(map -> map.entrySet().stream())
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                        Map.Entry::getKey,
                        e -> new ArrayList<>(e.getValue()),
                        (left, right) -> {left.addAll(right); return left;}
                ));
```

Note, I've changed  `e -> e.getValue().stream().collect(Collectors.toList())` to `new ArrayList<>(e.getValue())` to guarantee that we always have a mutable list which we can add into in the merge function.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe. But you are more likely to get everything right by combining the entries manually, using iteration. I don't know if anyone else will have to work on this code, but they will likely be grateful for an easy to read approach.

Answer (score 4):

You have to use the overloaded `toMap()` version that allows to merge duplicate keys :

```
toMap(Function<? super T, ? extends K> keyMapper,
                                    Function<? super T, ? extends U> valueMapper,
                                    BinaryOperator<U> mergeFunction)
```

You could write something as :

```
Map<String, List<String>> map3 = Stream.of(map1, map2)
    .flatMap(map -> map.entrySet().stream())
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        Map.Entry::getKey,
        e -> new ArrayList<>(e.getValue()),
        (e1, e2) -> { e1.addAll(e2); return e1;}
    ));
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also do it like this:

```
Map<String, List<String>> map3 = Stream.concat(map1.entrySet().stream(),
                                               map2.entrySet().stream())
      .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Entry::getKey,
                   Collectors.mapping(Entry::getValue,
                       Collectors.flatMapping(List::stream,
                           Collectors.toList()))));
```

Comment: I think, it’s simpler to use a single `flatMapping(e -> e.getValue().stream(), …)` instead of `Collectors.mapping(Entry::getValue, Collectors.flatMapping(List::stream, …))`. It doesn’t always have to be a method reference. Also, while the OP is using Java 9, the question has been tagged with Java 8, so it’? worth noting that `flatMapping` need Java 9.

Answer (score 3):

## Using flatmap twice

```
Map<String, List<String>> map1 = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, List<String>> map2 = new HashMap<>();

map1.put("k1", Arrays.asList("a0", "a1"));
map1.put("k2", Arrays.asList("b0", "b1"));

map2.put("k2", Arrays.asList("z1", "z2"));

Map<String, List<String>> map3 = Stream.of(map1, map2)
        .flatMap(p -> p.entrySet().stream())
        .flatMap(p -> p.getValue().stream().map(q -> new Pair<>(p.getKey(), q)))
        .collect(
                Collectors.groupingBy(
                        p -> p.getKey(),
                        Collectors.mapping(p -> p.getValue(), Collectors.toList())
                )
        );
```

This works like this:

- Takes both maps `Stream<Map<String,List<String>>>`
- FlatMaps the entries as `Entry<String, List<String>>`
- FlatMaps the entries into 1 pair per `Pair<String, String>`
- Collects them by their key

  - Taking the values, and collecting them into a list

Answer (score 1):

Here is one another way to merge maps and lists.

```
Map<String, List<String>> map3 = Stream.of(map1, map2)
    .flatMap(map -> map.entrySet().stream())
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        Map.Entry::getKey,
        Map.Entry::getValue,
        (e1, e2) -> Stream.concat(e1.stream(), e2.stream()).collect(Collectors.toList())
    ));
```

The third argument in `toMap` method is
`(e1, e2) -> Stream.concat(e1.stream(), e2.stream()).collect(Collectors.toList())` is `mergeFunction` function.
This function is applied to duplicates.

> If the mapped keys contains duplicates (according to `Object.equals(Object))`, the value mapping function is applied to each equal element, and the results are merged using the provided merging function.
>   [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using iteration of both maps. First iteration joins common key/value pairs from map1 and map2 together and adds them to the resulting map or adds unique key/value pairs in map1 to the resulting map. Second iteration grabs anything leftover in map2 that didnt match map1 and adds them to the resulting map.

```
public static Map<String, ArrayList<String>> joinMaps(Map<String, ArrayList<String>> map1, Map<String, ArrayList<String>> map2)
{
    Map<String, ArrayList<String>> mapJoined = new HashMap<>();

    //join values from map2 into values of map1 or add unique key/values of map1
    for (Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<String>> entry : map1.entrySet()) {
        String key = entry.getKey();
        ArrayList<String> value = entry.getValue();
        if(map2.containsKey(key))
        {
            value.addAll(map2.get(key));
            mapJoined.put(key, value);
        }
        else
            mapJoined.put(key, value);
    }

    //add the non-duplicates left over in map 2
    for (Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<String>> entry : map2.entrySet()) {
        if(!mapJoined.containsKey(entry.getKey()))
            mapJoined.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }

    return mapJoined;
}
```

You could also add a Set into the function to keep track of all keys added in the first iteration, then if the size of that Set == size of the map2 you know the maps have the same keys and there is no need to iterate second map, map2.

Answer (score 0):

other way would be like this.

you should init `map3` with larger map.(here `map1`). then use loop over other map and use `merge` method to combine duplicate key.

```
Map<String, List<String>> map3 = new HashMap<>(map1);
    for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : map2.entrySet()) {
       List<String> values = new ArrayList<>(entry.getValue());
       map3.merge(entry.getKey(),entry.getValue(),(l1, l2) -> {values.addAll(l1); 
           return values;
       });
    }
```

---

```
map2.forEach((key, value) -> {
    List<String> values = new ArrayList<>(value);
      map3.merge(key,value, (l1, l2) -> {values.addAll(l1);return values;});
});
```