# Java Stream Converting List<Map<String,Object>> to List<String, List<String>>

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a List of map,

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("a", "z");
map.put("b", "y");
.
.

Map<String, Object> map1 = new HashMap<>();
map1.put("a", "m");
map1.put("b", "n");
.
.

Map<String, Object> map2 = new HashMap<>();
map2.put("a", "p");
map2.put("b", "r");
.
.

List<Map<String,Object>> list = List.of(map, map1, map2);
```

My output should be grouped based on the Key from the Map as below to a
Map<String, List< String>>  the map values will be dynamic, so far 2 keys but it can be dynamic.

```
{ "a" : ["z","m", "p"], "b" : ["y", "n","r"], ....}
```

I've tried the below,

```
list.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toList(Collectors.groupingBy(list.stream().map (a -> a.keyset())), Arrays:asList);
```

I am not sure how to get the desired output.

Comment: A `List<String, List<String>>` is nonsense - a `List` is not a key/value collection (and has a single generic type). Did you mean a `Map<String, List<String>>`? In which case, using just `.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue)` on a flatmap'd stream of `Map.Entry` should suffice.

Comment: yeah you're right. Corrected.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merge map of arrays with duplicate keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50379529/merge-map-of-arrays-with-duplicate-keys)

Comment: No, My case is not Map<String, List<String> as per the reference. My situation is Map<String, Object>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Java 8 groupingBy**

You can achieve the scenario by using the `groupingBy` feature. You can first merge all the list of multiple maps into a single list of map by using the `flatmap` and then collect it by grouping it by key.

**Please Note:**

*Here I have also handled the below cases:*

1. If any of the map contains the `null` as a key. It will ignore that entry.
2. If any of the map contains the `null` as a value.It will have the null as an entry in the list.If required we can have any value instead of null as an element of the list.

**Please find the code below:**

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("a", "z");
        map.put("b", "y");
        map.put("c", null);

        Map<String, Object> map1 = new HashMap<>();
        map1.put("a", "m");
        map1.put("b", "n");
        map1.put(null, "aa");
        map1.put("c", null);

        Map<String, Object> map2 = new HashMap<>();
        map2.put("a", "p");
        map2.put("b", null);
        map2.put(null, "x");
        map2.put("c", null);

        List<Map<String,Object>> list = List.of(map, map1, map2);
        Map<String,List<String>> output = 
                list.stream()
                .flatMap(x -> x.entrySet().stream().filter(y -> y.getKey()!=null))
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey,
                        Collectors.mapping(x -> x.getValue()!=null ? x.getValue().toString(): null,Collectors.toList())));
        System.out.println(output);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
{a=[z, m, p], b=[y, n, null], c=[null, null, null]}
```